# After clicking verification link, how to redirect mail to app in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

// Sending the verification link to its respected email..

```
func requestForVerification() {
        if verify {
            verifyEmailApi.verifyEmail(email: emailTxtField.text!) { (status , message) in
                if status {
                    self.simpleAlert(title: "Alert", message: message)
                } else {
                    self.simpleAlert(title: "Error", message: message)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

// Link is send to the email.. after clicking it.. It should redirect or jump back to the app with success of verfication popup in app..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Deep Linking` but Apple recommends to use `Universal links` which is more secure. Here is an entire video on how to do these. [Deep Linking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUA6BR-BUTY) and [Universal Linking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEXn7QIwPFo).